# Mqtt Client works on Node.js, doesn't on Python

Tags: python, node.js, mqtt

I'm trying to make a small script that grabs **ShareNow**'s cars information and does stuff with it.
When looking online for an api I've only found [this](https://github.com/T3rm1/share-now-api) GitHub repo in which he uses Node.js to connect to an mqtt broker and get information about the cars.

Now, I've never used Node and I've never heard of mqtt before, however i tried to translate the part of the code in which he connects to the broker in python and it doesn't work, i can't seem to find a way to translate this lines

```js
let client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://driver.eu.share-now.com:443', {
    clientId,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    reconnectPeriod: 0
});
```

into a way to connect to the broker outside of Node.js. What i have understood is that the url is *driver.eu.share-now.com* and the port is *443*, i don't know if it's correct but when i try to connect to it (either with python or with an outside program) it just sits doing nothing or times out.

The thing that i don't understand is why and how it works on his code, but even trying on mqtt client testers i can't find a way to connect.

Here's a simplified (and still working) version of the GitHub code in node.js:

```js
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
const uuid = require("uuid-random");
const zlib = require("zlib");


class ShareNowClient {
    static VEHICLELIST = "C2G/S2C/20/VEHICLELIST.GZ"
    vehicles = [];
    #updateCallback;

    connect() {
        let clientId = `a:${uuid()}`;
        let client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://driver.eu.share-now.com:443', {
            clientId,
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
            reconnectPeriod: 0
        });

        client.on('connect', () => {
            client.subscribe(ShareNowClient.VEHICLELIST, {qos: 0});
        });

        client.on("message", (topic, message) => {
            let json = JSON.parse(zlib.gunzipSync(message));
            if (topic === ShareNowClient.VEHICLELIST) {
                client.unsubscribe(ShareNowClient.VEHICLELIST);
                this.vehicles = json.connectedVehicles;
                console.log(this.vehicles[0]) //prints the first vehicle to check if it works
                client.end();
            }
        });

        client.on("error", error => {
            console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
        });
    }
}

let cars = new ShareNowClient();
cars.connect();
```

And here is what i tried in python (it obviously doesn't work)

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import uuid

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc): 
    print("Connected with result code {0}".format(str(rc)))
    client.subscribe(topic)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg): 
    print(str(msg.payload))
    #print("Message received-> " + msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))

clientId = f'a:{uuid.uuid4()}'

client = mqtt.Client(clientId)  
client.on_connect = on_connect 
client.on_message = on_message


broker = 'driver.eu.share-now.com'
port = 443
topic = "C2G/S2C/20/VEHICLELIST.GZ"

client.connect(broker , port)
client.loop_forever()
```

The python code works when i try to connect to a test broker, but just loops doing nothing when i try to connect to the url of sharenow.

Can anybody help make it work? thanks

Comment: Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't give us anything to work with. What have you done to try and debug this and what if any errors are shown?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i fixed the post to make it more understandable. In any case the thing that doesn't work is (probably) the 'url' that i use to connect to the broker, i tried with implicit and explicit protocols and changing the port but i still don't understand how to connect to it outside of node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL you passed to the NodeJS client starts with `mqtts://` which signifies a MQTT over TLS connection, since you've not told the python client that you are trying to connect to a TLS enabled broker it is not trying to do a TLS handshake.

Adding `client.tls_set()` before the call to `client.connect()` will fix the problem.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import uuid

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc): 
    print("Connected with result code {0}".format(str(rc)))
    client.subscribe(topic)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg): 
    print(str(msg.payload))
    #print("Message received-> " + msg.topic + " " + str(msg.payload))

clientId = f'a:{uuid.uuid4()}'

client = mqtt.Client(clientId)  
client.on_connect = on_connect 
client.on_message = on_message


broker = 'driver.eu.share-now.com'
port = 443
topic = "C2G/S2C/20/VEHICLELIST.GZ"

client.tls_set()

client.connect(broker , port)
client.loop_forever()
```